# get index of complex array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this `var_dump($result)`:

```
$result = array(
    array("Start" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Driving route" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Lunch-Rest Break" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Break" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Waiting" => array("xxxx")),
    array("End" => array("xxxx"))s
);
```

How can I get the index of a given key? For instance I wanted to get the index of the key "Break" I did as folowing :

```
$key = array_search('Break', $result);
```

`$key` is empty I get no index.

Thanks.

Comment: [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is __not__ recursive, but there's plenty of examples in the PHP manual doc page comments showing ways of implementing a recursive array search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function :

```
$result = array(
    array("Start" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Driving route" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Lunch-Rest Break" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Break" => array("xxxx")),
    array("Waiting" => array("xxxx")),
    array("End" => array("xxxx"))
);

function searchKeyIndex($array, $key) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if(isset($array[$i][$key])) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}

echo searchKeyIndex($result, "Break");
```

**Output** : 3